# Append item in select2 on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I'm using select2 tag style in my Drupal YAML form, so users can find and add some items.

All those items I have with images and title on the same page, and beside each image I have button. I want to enable user to click on the button and to add that item in select2 (just like with select2 dropdown list).

I tried something like this:

```
$('a.rentiraj').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                // Get title
                var masina = $(this).closest('.views-row').find('.views-field-title span').text();
                // Result to add in select2 ul
                var result = '<li class="select2-selection__choice" title="' + masina + '"><span class="select2-selection__choice__remove" role="presentation">×</span>' + masina + '</li>';
                // Add result in select2 ul before last li
                $('.select2-selection ul li:last-child').before(result);
            });
```

But without success. Item is added when I click on button, but I can't remove it when click 'X' besides item in select2 and if I add item from select2 dropdown list all items disappears and there is only item added from select2 dropdown list.

Can someone point me to the right direction? How I can add new item in select2, not from dropdown list, but from outside this list when I click on button?

This is the first time that I'm working with select2. I'm using it through [YAML Form](https://www.drupal.org/project/yamlform) Drupal 8 module.

Answer (score 0):

use ON from jquery instead click method :

```
$('a.rentiraj').on('click', function (e) {
```

Documentation : http://api.jquery.com/on/